# Hybrid Encryption with AES and RSA - How secure does the AES secret key need to be?

Tags: android, cryptography, aes, rsa, keystore

I'm in need of storing in shared preferences a bunch of sensitive information. I know using EncryptedSharedPreferences would be ideal, but given its minSDKVersion of 23, its a no-go for me.

So, I chose to implement an hybrid cryptography system.

1. The first time I need to encrypt some data, **I randomly generate an AES secret key**
2. Then, I create a **new entry in the keystore**, so that I can use its **public key to encrypt that AES secret key**. Then, that final **secret key is saved in shared prefs**
3. Whenever I need to access that data, I'll get the encrypted key from shared prefs, **decrypt it using the private key stored in the key store** and, finally, **decrypt the content with the AES key** that I just retrieved.

Am I doing it the right way? I'm currently **not using any IV or padding in the AES encryption**. I figure this system will be just as secure as the RSA algorithm I used, no matter what the AES key is (as long as it is a random one generated at run time). Am I right or missing something? Should I take the extra step of using a padding and IV alongside AES?

Comment: IV and padding are likely still very important. There are only a few cases where IV can be static. Also, the mode of operation is pretty important. Are you using AES-GCM?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm actually implementing the default set (Cipher.getInstance("AES")), so I think it's actually AES-ECB (which is the less secure, I know).

Comment: `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` is most likely `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5padding")`, but depends on your JRE. Always use a fully qualified cipher.